# How to make search and text in row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, flutter-textinputfield

I have tried to make it in the row, but then I don't have anything in the screen.
How do you solve it in Flutter?

appbar

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 10.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Goals",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
```

search

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: Container(
        height: 55,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            hintText: "Search",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

in Screen
I have tried make these two widgets it in Row, but doesn't work

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            const CustomAppBar(),
            const SearchBar(),
```

This is my result:

[image: Example]

EDIT:

```
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  child: Text("Goals"),
                ),
                Expanded(child: MyPrefilledSearch()),
              ],
            ),
```

```
class MyPrefilledSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPrefilledSearch({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPrefilledSearch> createState() => _MyPrefilledSearchState();
}

class _MyPrefilledSearchState extends State<MyPrefilledSearch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoSearchTextField(
      onChanged: (String value) {
        print('The text has changed to: $value');
      },
      onSubmitted: (String value) {
        print('Submitted text: $value');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Looks fine :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Yi4.png)

My post is code because it is I do not need add more text because it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CupertinoSearchTextField()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSearchTextField-class.html)

Example from doc

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Center(
    child: CupertinoSearchTextField(),
  ),
),
```

[image]

```dart
 Row(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text("Goals"),
    ),
    Expanded(child: CupertinoSearchTextField()),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm but If you would like to add like:
Goals: [Search Bar] I would like ot have it "Goals" textfield

Comment: Does last Update snippet answer your question

Comment: Yep, I have updated the code what exactly I have done. THANKS MAN!:)